# Task switcher on Lubuntu 20.04 showing all tasks instead of task from current workspace

Tags: lubuntu, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I am using Lubuntu 20.04.03 LTS (Ubuntu + LXQT, bassically), fresh install. I can configure Task Manager to show only windows from current desktop (workspace), but the task switcher still shows windows from all desktops. Is there a way I can synchronize both? Before upgrading (18.04) behaviour was as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lubuntu 20.04 has LXQT desktop by default. You installed LXDE next to LXQT ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was not aware of this. I edited the question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: Please note:  Upgrading is **not** supported for a reason, thus why you find "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*" in the release notes. eg. https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/   An upgraded system may have *issues* not present in a *clean* install; LXDE used by 18.04 was a different *deprecated* desktop using *deprecated* libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, before I had 18.04 but the 20.04 is a fresh install, not an upgrade

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for my problem. In the keys binding configuration file (now in ~/.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml) the combination config for switching between windows is `A-Tab`. That's right, but there's also an option called `<allDesktops>`. In my case it said `yes`, I changed it to `no` and now it shows only windows from the current desktop.

Comment: Well done! This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the panel. First option in *Task Manager Settings* is *Show only windows from desktop*.

[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zxw14q2JO03OwuYJ3mvqFCroMEKWOtNb/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that option is already ticked, so in the task bar I can see only windows from the current desktop, BUT the task switcher (Alt + Tab) shows windows from ALL desktops. That's why I talk about synchronizity.